# Code Syntax Highlighting in Delphi 6 (to highlight syntax and ifdef blocks)

Tags: delphi, ide, plugins, syntax-highlighting, delphi-6

Delphi 6 is pretty old, I know.  Unfortunately there are reasons why I can't upgrade which I don't want to get into here.

My problem is that it's hard to read code.  I have the Castalia plugin which helps a bit (parenthesis matching, shows blocks of if, else, end) but it doesn't highlight the syntax like other IDEs do (variables, constants, procedures, etc.) in different colors.  It also doesn't show the IFDEF blocks which can be very confusing at times.

For Delphi 6 what plugins can do some or all of these features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CnPack will work on Delphi6, and it highlights {$whatever} symbols. 
http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en

Comment: Does it only highlight the {$anything} line, or all the space inbetween?  The issue I'm looking to solve is that I can't tell which ifdef a block belongs to.

Comment: @Daisetsu - sorry, it only highlights the syntax, not the blocks.  Too bad, as it does a nice job highlighting begin..end blocks, if..then.else, etc..